# Disable CSS animation on page load but work every other time

Tags: javascript, css, animation

How do I make a CSS animation not to play on page load, but to play every other time apart from the very first time when the page loads? I have the following:

```
.anim{
    animation:  animate 0.6s
}

@keyframes animate{
    from{transform: rotate(180deg)}
    to{transform: rotate(0deg)}
}
```

So the first time the page loads, the `.anim` container rotates, but I intend to trigger the rotation later using an `onclick` event. The `anim` class is applied by default, and once the `onclick` event is called, the `anim` class is removed, and another class with it's own animation is applied to the element. The animation above is meant to play as a transition from the `anim` class to the other class. How do I make it play only at transition time and not when the page completes loading? Is there a way I can apply the `anim` class using JavaScript after page load, but prevent the animation from playing?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code in a way that you give the class `.anim` to your container when the `onclick` event occurs. Then add a `animationend` listener to your container that will add the class you want when the animation will end.

Comment: some code as examples would help who is not very into javascript

Comment: @Saba i'd need some code to modify it, OP provided none.

Comment: The `.anim` class contains other styling rules, so I can't wait for an `onclick` event to apply the styles.

Comment: @TroubleZero then split the .anim class into 2 classes. One with the css rules you want to be there at loading, and another one with the css rules you want to happen when you click on it :)

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically start animations, you should add the class which applies said animation. You can also take advantage of the 'animationend', 'animationstart' and 'animationiteration' events that are triggered on the animated elements. In your specific case, where you want an animation to play, right before another class is added, you might want to just have ONE class that does what you want, and add that. But if you want to use two classed you could do.

```
function addFirstClass(e){
  var tar= e.target;
  tar.addEventListener('animationend', addSecondClass);
  tar.classList.add('className');
}

function addSecondClass(e) {
  var tar= e.target;
  tar.removeEventListener('animationend', addSecondClass);
  tar.classList.remove('className');
  tar.classList.add('newClass');
}
```